# Como colocar Outlines no texto

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Gostaria de saber como colocar outlines pretas no texto

```
    JLabel label_name = new JLabel();
    label_name.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
    label_name.setForeground(Color.white);
    label_name.setText("Este é um exemplo");
    inner_third_panel.add(label_name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma saida seria utilizar este source para fazer o que você deseja:

```
    import java.awt.BasicStroke;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.GradientPaint;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.Insets;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.awt.RenderingHints;
    import java.awt.Shape;
    import java.awt.Stroke;
    import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
    import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
    import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
    import java.awt.font.TextLayout;
    import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

    public class JLabel2D extends JLabel {
      public static final int EFFECT_PLAIN = 0;

      public static final int EFFECT_GRADIENT = 1;

      public static final int EFFECT_IMAGE = 2;

      public static final int EFFECT_IMAGE_ANIMATION = 3;

      public static final int EFFECT_COLOR_ANIMATION = 4;

      protected int effectIndex = EFFECT_PLAIN;

      protected double shearFactor = 0.0;

      protected Color outlineColor;

      protected Stroke stroke;

      protected GradientPaint gradient;

      protected Image foregroundImage;

      protected Thread animator;

      protected boolean isRunning = false;

      protected int m_delay;

      protected int m_xShift;

      public JLabel2D() {
        super();
      }

      public JLabel2D(String text) {
        super(text);
      }

      public JLabel2D(String text, int alignment) {
        super(text, alignment);
      }

      public void setEffectIndex(int e) {
        effectIndex = e;
        repaint();
      }

      public int getEffectIndex() {
        return effectIndex;
      }

      public void setShearFactor(double s) {
        shearFactor = s;
        repaint();
      }

      public double getShearFactor() {
        return shearFactor;
      }

      public void setOutlineColor(Color c) {
        outlineColor = c;
        repaint();
      }

      public Color getOutlineColor() {
        return outlineColor;
      }

      public void setStroke(Stroke s) {
        stroke = s;
        repaint();
      }

      public Stroke getStroke() {
        return stroke;
      }

      public void setGradient(GradientPaint g) {
        gradient = g;
        repaint();
      }

      public GradientPaint getGradient() {
        return gradient;
      }

      public void setForegroundImage(Image img) {
        foregroundImage = img;
        repaint();
      }

      public Image getForegroundImage() {
        return foregroundImage;
      }

      public void startAnimation(int delay) {
        if (animator != null)
          return;
        m_delay = delay;
        m_xShift = 0;
        isRunning = true;
        animator = new Thread() {
          double arg = 0;
          public void run() {
            while (isRunning) {
              if (effectIndex == EFFECT_IMAGE_ANIMATION)
                m_xShift += 10;
              else if (effectIndex == EFFECT_COLOR_ANIMATION
                  && gradient != null) {
                arg += Math.PI / 10;
                double cos = Math.cos(arg);
                double f1 = (1 + cos) / 2;
                double f2 = (1 - cos) / 2;
                arg = arg % (Math.PI * 2);

                Color c1 = gradient.getColor1();
                Color c2 = gradient.getColor2();
                int r = (int) (c1.getRed() * f1 + c2.getRed() * f2);
                r = Math.min(Math.max(r, 0), 255);
                int g = (int) (c1.getGreen() * f1 + c2.getGreen() * f2);
                g = Math.min(Math.max(g, 0), 255);
                int b = (int) (c1.getBlue() * f1 + c2.getBlue() * f2);
                b = Math.min(Math.max(b, 0), 255);
                setForeground(new Color(r, g, b));
              }
              repaint();
              try {
                sleep(m_delay);
              } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                break;
              }
            }
          }
        };
        animator.start();
      }

      public void stopAnimation() {
        isRunning = false;
        animator = null;
      }

      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Dimension d = getSize();
        Insets ins = getInsets();
        int x = ins.left;
        int y = ins.top;
        int w = d.width - ins.left - ins.right;
        int h = d.height - ins.top - ins.bottom;

        if (isOpaque()) {
          g.setColor(getBackground());
          g.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
        }
        paintBorder(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

        FontRenderContext frc = g2.getFontRenderContext();
        TextLayout tl = new TextLayout(getText(), getFont(), frc);

        AffineTransform shear = AffineTransform.getShearInstance(shearFactor,
            0.0);
        Shape src = tl.getOutline(shear);
        Rectangle rText = src.getBounds();

        float xText = x - rText.x;
        switch (getHorizontalAlignment()) {
        case CENTER:
          xText = x + (w - rText.width) / 2;
          break;
        case RIGHT:
          xText = x + (w - rText.width);
          break;
        }
        float yText = y + h / 2 + tl.getAscent() / 4;

        AffineTransform shift = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(xText,
            yText);
        Shape shp = shift.createTransformedShape(src);

        if (outlineColor != null) {
          g2.setColor(outlineColor);
          if (stroke != null)
            g2.setStroke(stroke);
          g2.draw(shp);
        }

        switch (effectIndex) {
        case EFFECT_GRADIENT:
          if (gradient == null)
            break;
          g2.setPaint(gradient);
          g2.fill(shp);
          break;

        case EFFECT_IMAGE:
          fillByImage(g2, shp, 0);
          break;

        case EFFECT_COLOR_ANIMATION:
          g2.setColor(getForeground());
          g2.fill(shp);
          break;

        case EFFECT_IMAGE_ANIMATION:
          if (foregroundImage == null)
            break;
          int wImg = foregroundImage.getWidth(this);
          if (m_xShift > wImg)
            m_xShift = 0;
          fillByImage(g2, shp, m_xShift - wImg);
          break;

        default:
          g2.setColor(getForeground());
          g2.fill(shp);
          break;
        }
      }

      protected void fillByImage(Graphics2D g2, Shape shape, int xOffset) {
        if (foregroundImage == null)
          return;
        int wImg = foregroundImage.getWidth(this);
        int hImg = foregroundImage.getHeight(this);
        if (wImg <= 0 || hImg <= 0)
          return;
        g2.setClip(shape);
        Rectangle bounds = shape.getBounds();
        for (int xx = bounds.x + xOffset; xx < bounds.x + bounds.width; xx += wImg)
          for (int yy = bounds.y; yy < bounds.y + bounds.height; yy += hImg)
            g2.drawImage(foregroundImage, xx, yy, this);
      }
    }
```

Então com o codigo a seguir conseguiria fazer o que você deseja:

```
JLabel label_name = new JLabel2D("Este é um exemplo", JLabel.CENTER)
label_name.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
label_name.setForeground(Color.white);    
label_name.setOutlineColor(Color.black);
inner_third_panel.add(label_name);
```

FONTE: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Labelwithvariouseffects.htm

Comment: melkysalem, respostas somente com links não são consideradas boas porque o link pode deixar de existir a qualquer momento. Isso fica melhor, talvez, como um comentário. No entanto, talvez você possa editar a resposta acrescentando o trecho de código relevante ou alguma explicação sobre os métodos/objetos usados na solução.